# Directory Structure for a unix like file system

Tags: c++, unix, filesystems, directory-structure

I am currently in a Systems Software class and our final project is to implement implement a simple  unix like shell environment and file system with a hierarchical directory structure. We have done the easy part of asking the user for a command like 'cd xxx' or 'ls'. And once each command is called, it goes to a function. I know I need a tree like data structure for the directories and files, but I just don't know where to start. I know that a parent can only be a directory. The directory has a name and can take other directories and files. A file only has a name. How do I go about implementing this kind of code? Here is all I have right now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>


void makeFS(){
    printf("You created and formatted a new filesystem.\n");
}

void listDir(){
    printf("Listing all entries in current directory...\n");
}

void exitShell(){
    printf("Adios amigo.\n");
    exit(0);
}

void makeDir(char name[50]){

   printf("Directory [%s] created at !\n", name);
}

void remDir(char cmd[50]){
    printf("You entered %s \n", cmd);
}

void changeDir(char *nextName){
    printf("Changed directory path to %s\n", nextName);
}

void status(char cmd[50]){
    printf("You entered %s \n", cmd);
}

void makeFile(char cmd[50]){
    printf("You entered %s \n", cmd);
}

void remFile(char cmd[50]){
    printf("You entered %s \n", cmd);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char cmd[50];
    const char spc[50] = " \n";
    char *file, *dir;
    char *tok, *nextName;


    while (1){
        printf("Russ_John_Shell> ");
        fgets(cmd, 50, stdin);

        //Tokenizes string to determine what command was inputed as well as     any file/directory name needed
        tok = strtok(cmd, spc);
        nextName = strtok(NULL, spc);


        //Checks to see whether the string has a file/directory name after the command
        if (nextName == NULL){
            //mkfs command
            if (strcmp(cmd, "mkfs") == 0){
                makeFS();
            }
            //exit command
            else if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0){
                exitShell();
            } 
            //ls command
            else if (strcmp(cmd, "ls") == 0){
                listDir();
            }
            //command not recognized at all
            else {
                printf("Command not recognized.\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            //mkdir command
            if (strcmp(cmd, "mkdir") == 0){
                makeDir(nextName);
            }
            //rmdir command
            else if (strcmp(cmd, "rmdir") == 0){
                remDir(cmd);
            }
            //cd command
            else if (strcmp(cmd, "cd") == 0){
                changeDir(nextName);
            }
            //stat command
            else if (strcmp(cmd, "stat") == 0){
                status(cmd);
            }
            //mkfile command
            else if (strcmp(cmd, "mkfile") == 0){
                makeFile(cmd);
            }    
            //rmfile command
            else if (strcmp(cmd, "rmfile") == 0){
                remFile(cmd);
            }
            //command not recognized at all
            else {
                printf("Command not recognized.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, get rid of all those `cmd[50]` declarations.  Define a parameter, like `#define CMDLEN 50`.

Comment: @paulsm4 Or better yet, use `std::string` since this is tagged C++.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use boost.filesystem?
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm